# Is my proof that the product of covering spaces is a covering space correct?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification

Let $p_1:\tilde X_1  \rightarrow X_1$ and $p_2:\tilde X_2  \rightarrow X_2$ be two covering spaces. Prove: $p = p_1 \times p_2:\tilde X_1 \times \tilde X_2  \rightarrow X_1 \times X_2$ is a covering space.

Clearly $p$ is surjective and continuous, and given $x \in X_1 \times X_2$ and an open set $U$ s.t. $x \in U$, $p^{-1}(U) = p_1^{-1}(U_{x_1}) \times p_2^{-1}(U_{x_2}) $, which is a product of a union of disjoint open sets and therefore is a union of disjoint and open sets.

I'm pretty sure my proof is wrong, I think that the actual proof has something to do with the fundamental groups of the spaces but I can't quite understand how the fundamental group relates to the covering space.

Is this proof wrong?

Comment: I presume that you are missing some hypotheses: $p_1$ and $p_2$ should be covering maps. In which case I would point out that your proof has not used these hypotheses.

Comment: Yes, thanks I added that just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is indeed wrong.

For a counterexample, consider the case where $\tilde X_1 = X_1 = \mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde X_2 = X_2 = \mathbb{R}$ and $p_1,p_2,p$ are all simply identity maps. In that case, you would be saying that for any open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, letting $V = p^{-1}(U)=U$, the set $V$ can be written as a product $V = A \times B$ for some sets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

But this is not possible: not every open subset $V \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ can be written in the form $V = A \times B$. Think, for example, of the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ of radius $1$ centered on the origin $O = (0,0)$:
$$V = B(O,1) = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \bigm| x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}
$$
This open ball **is not equal to** any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $A \times B$, for any $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

To summarize, your proof uses the statement that every open subset of the Cartesian $\tilde X_1 \times \tilde X_2$ is a Cartesian product of an open subset of $\tilde X_1$ times an open subset of $\tilde X_2$. This statement is false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the fact that $p = p_1 \times p_2$ change anything? Because then by definition $p^{-1} $is what I wrote.. or is it?

Comment: No, it is not. Once again, an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives a counterexample. I've tried to rewrite my answer to conform more with the notation of your question, so that you can see the error more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for this. If it's not too much of a bother, is this last try correct?: For a given $x \in X_1 \times X_2$ there is an open set in $\tilde X_1$ that $p_1$ maps to on open set $U \subset X_1$ s.t. $x \in U \times X_2$, we can find another open set $V$for $x$'s other coordinate $X_2$ and then we are done (product of open is open)

Comment: That's beginning to sound more reasonable. But it would be more straightforward to do something like this: given $x=(x_1,x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$, use the fact that $p_1$ is a covering map to choose an open set $U_1 \subset X_1$ containing $x_1$ which is evenly covered by $p_1$, and use the fact that $p_2$ is a covering map to choose an open set $U_2 \subset X_2$ containing $x_2$ which is evenly covered by $p_2$. Then prove that $U_1 \times U_2$ is an open set containing $x$ that is evenly covered by $p_1 \times p_2$.

Comment: Bearing in mind the product topology, it seems reasonable to take $\mathcal{U} := \{U_1 × X_2 \mid U_1 ∈ \mathcal{U_1} \} ∪  \{X_1 × U_2 \mid U_2 ∈ \mathcal{U_2} \}$ as the desired open cover, where  $\mathcal{U_i}$ is the open cover of $X_i$ that exists by virtue of the $p_i$ being covering maps. Would this make the result (almost) immediate?